# How to solve $ \displaystyle\int \bigg(\small\sqrt{\normalsize x+\small\sqrt{\normalsize x+\sqrt{ x+\sqrt{x}}}}\;\normalsize\bigg)\;dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this:

$$\displaystyle\int \bigg(\small\sqrt{\normalsize x +\small\sqrt{\normalsize x +\small\sqrt{\normalsize x +\sqrt{x}}}}\;\normalsize\bigg) \;dx$$

Comment: Seems like this is a tough one, at least mathematica cannot find it http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Sqrt[x+%2B+Sqrt[x+%2B+Sqrt[x%2BSqrt[x]]]]%2Cx]

Comment: I don't think that integral is huge enough.

Comment: What does it mean to "solve" an anti-derivative?

Comment: You could try a series expansion.

Comment: I can help with $I=\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}dx$: Let $u(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Then $dx=2\sqrt{x}du$ and $I$ becomes $I=\int \sqrt{u^2 + u}2udu$. We integrate by parts and $I=2[\frac{u}{2\sqrt{u^2+u}}-\int \sqrt{u^2+u}du]$. Let $J=\int \sqrt{u^2+u}du$. Then $J=\frac{1+2u}{4}\sqrt{u^2+u}-\frac{1}{8}ln |2u+1+2\sqrt{u^2+u}|+c$ (from tables).

Comment: Just let $u=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}$ is OK. Then you will get $x$ in terms of polynomial of $u$. WolframAlpha canot solve it because the process time is excessed.

Answer (score 4):

While this is not an answer, I posted it as an answer so that I can attach the graph.
On the graph you can see how close the 2 functions are. Using this fact may help.

The Black graph is the original function and the Red graph is for the approximate function.

[image]

A better approximation for the function $f(x)=\displaystyle\bigg(\small\sqrt{\normalsize x+\small\sqrt{\normalsize x+\sqrt{ x+\sqrt{x}}}}\;\normalsize\bigg)$ is:

$0.5(1+\sqrt[]{1+4x})$

This approximation was obtained from [Nested Radicals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical), This formula is an exact value for the infinite case, so it may be used as an approximation only in your case.

A picture of the 2 functions is shown below.
The Black graph is the original function and the Red graph is for the approximate function.

[image]

Comment: How did you come up with this approximation? Can you post the proof that it asymptotically approximates the given function?

Comment: In fact I can't claim that it an optimal approximation since I came across it by plotting various curves and noticed that this one was among the better ones. The main point I wanted to show is that there may be a good approximation for the original function that may help.